# decrease html headings using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, html, xml, elementtree

Is there a recursive way to decrease all the heading levels in a HTLM tree, using Python ElementTree? 
In the example below h1 would become h2, and so consequently for the other headings.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import html5lib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

headings = '''<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Sub Title</h2>
<h3>Sub sub title 1</h3>
<h3>Sub sub title 2</h3>
<h4>Sub sub sub title<h4>
<h3>Sub sub title</h3>
'''
tree = html5lib.parse(headings, namespaceHTMLElements=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example, but using the awesome [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headings = '''<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Sub Title</h2>
<h3>Sub sub title 1</h3>
<h3>Sub sub title 2</h3>
<h4>Sub sub sub title</h4>
<h3>Sub sub title</h3>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(headings, "html.parser")
pattern = re.compile(r"^h(\d)$")
for tag in soup.find_all(pattern):
    tag.name = "h%d" % (int(pattern.match(tag.name).group(1)) + 1)

print(soup)
```

We are locating all elements with the tag name matching the `^h(\d)$` pattern (`h` followed by a single digit; `^` means the beginning of a string, `$` - the end). Then, we extract the digit and increase it by one and update the tag name.

Prints:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<h3>Sub Title</h3>
<h4>Sub sub title 1</h4>
<h4>Sub sub title 2</h4>
<h5>Sub sub sub title</h5>
<h4>Sub sub title</h4>
```

Comment: thanks @alecxe. I am trying to avoid using external libraries such as beautiful soup of lxml. However your answer made think how could I do it using Etree. I'll put an example in a new answer

Answer (score 1):

element.tag=newtag does the trick. All that needs to be done is adding one value to the heading.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import html5lib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

headings = '''<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Sub Title</h2>
<h3>Sub sub title 1</h3>
<h3>Sub sub title 2</h3>
<h4>Sub sub sub title<h4>
<h3>Sub sub title</h3>
<p>paragrap</p>
'''

tree = html5lib.parse(headings, namespaceHTMLElements=False)
headings = [el for el in tree.findall('.//') if el.tag in ["h1","h2", "h3", "h4","h5","h6"]]

for h in headings:
    newtag =  h.tag[0]+ str(int(h.tag[-1])+1)
    h.tag=newtag

print ET.tostring(headings)
```